# Customizing conditional email confirmations

Tags: cognito-forms, notifications, customization

I would like to set for the confirmation e-mail item "Send when updated" by condition When: "Entry.Status is not Reviewed". I set up all correctly by my opinion, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

I tried to set up the same 'When Updated' condition for my own Confirmation Email. In my testing I found that the confirmation email was sent out on submit, and when the status was changed to 'Complete'. I did not get an email when the entry transferred over to 'Reviewed'.

The 'When Updated' status I used is 'Entry.Status is not Reviewed' if you switch over to the Advanced Editor, you should see the following calculation.

```
=(Entry.Status != "Reviewed")
```

If you're not seeing the correct interaction with your form please submit a [Support Request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/) so that we can take a closer look at the form your working with.